# rails g model no funciona

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

tengo este problema, ya he intentado unas cuantas soluciones que ofrece San Google pero no he llegado al grano. La máquina es una *i7* con *Windows 7 32b*, y con *ruby 2.3.3* y *rails 5.1.2*. Estaré muy agradecido con su ayuda.

```
C:\Users\Ernesto\Documents\folderRails\test_app>rails generate model User email name provider uid
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error whi
le trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/r
ails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:58:in `autodetect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:
5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:
4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier
.rb:5:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier
.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:82:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:77:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:66:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:66:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.
rb:108:in `require'
C:/Users/Amanda/Documents/folderRails/poll_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
(required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/co
mmand/actions.rb:15:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/co
mmand/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/co
mmands/generate/generate_command.rb:19:in `perform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/comman
d.rb:27:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invoca
tion.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369
:in `dispatch'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/co
mmand/base.rb:63:in `perform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/co
mmand.rb:44:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1
/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Amanda/Documents/folderRails/poll_app/config/application.r
b:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:19:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/li
b/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Tal vez haciendo `bundle install`? Otra opción puede ser: `gem install uglifier`. Esto porque el error comienza con: `There was an error whi
le trying to load the gem 'uglifier'`

Comment: Para complementar el comentario anterior, puedes obtener la versión de Node.js para windows [aquí](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, el error que se te presenta es por que tienes que tener instalado node JS, date una vuelta por acá e instalalo.

https://nodejs.org/es/

Espero te haya podido servir. saludos.